# Lipschitz constant of function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Consider the function $$f_{n}(x)=\min\{1, \frac{1}{\ln n}\ln_{+}\left(\frac{n^{2}}{|x|}\right)\}.$$ Clearly we have that $supp(f_{n})=B(0, n^{2})$ but is this function Lipschitz and if it is indeed, what is the Lipschitz constant? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer [How to show $\min\{f_1,f_2\}$ is Lipschitz when $f_1,f_2$ are Lipschitz?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527111/how-to-show-min-f-1-f-2-is-lipschitz-when-f-1-f-2-are-lipschitz) it was proved that the minimum of two lipschitz functions is lipschitz. Thus also the maximum of two lipschitz functions is lipschitz. Hence, your function is lipschitz. To compute the lipschitz constant you may use that your function is piecewise smooth and you can just compute the supremum of the derivatives (only the $\ln$ term will matter on its domain).

The function is constant except on $B(0,n^2)\setminus B(0,n)$. This means the lipschitz constant is equal to
$$ \max_{\vert x \vert\in [n, n^2]} \left\vert \nabla\left( \frac{1}{\ln(n)} \ln\left( \frac{n^2}{\vert x \vert}\right) \right) \right\vert
= \frac{1}{\vert \ln(n) \vert} \max_{\vert x \vert\in [n, n^2]} \left\vert\left( \nabla \ln\left( \frac{1}{\vert x \vert}\right) \right) \right\vert
= \frac{1}{\vert \ln(n) \vert} \max_{\vert x \vert\in [n, n^2]} \left\vert \frac{1}{\vert x \vert} \frac{x}{\vert x \vert}  \right\vert
= \frac{1}{\vert \ln(n) \vert} \max_{\vert x \vert\in [n, n^2]} \frac{1}{\vert x \vert} = \frac{1}{ \vert \ln(n) \vert \cdot n}$$

Comment: What is when $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: Then we need to compute the gradient. What case are you interested in?

Comment: We should have $|\nabla (f_{n})|^{2}=|\frac{1}{\ln (n)|x|}|^{2}$...

Comment: actually I am interested in the case when $f_{n}$ is defined on a Riemannian manifold and $|x|=d(x, x_{0})$ is the geodesic distance...

Comment: I think this function does not work for my purposes... do you know a Lipschitz function with compact support in $B(x_{0}, n)$ $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{n}\uparrow 1$ with Lipschitz constant $=n^{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!... I write $|x|=d(x, x_{0})$, so no confusion

Comment: We can take it radial: $f_n(x) = \varphi(\vert x - x_0 \vert)$ with $$ \varphi(r) = \begin{cases} 1,& r\in [0,n-1/n^2] \\ 0,& r\in [n,\infty) \end{cases} $$ and linear interpolation in between. Now it is correct.

Comment: But this only works with the usual norm. I don't know how to do it on a general riemannian manifold. Because then we would also need to control the derivative of the metric. For the usual norm this is easy as we can explicitely compute everything.